# FullCalendar 1.5.4 - EventResized doesn't fire in week or day view

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resize, fullcalendar

I tried upgrading to FullCalendar 1.5.4 but when I did the eventResized event never gets called when resizing an event in the week or day view.  I am using the exact same scripts as the demo:

```
jquery v 1.8.1
jquery-ui v1.8.23
fullcalendar v1.5.4
```

I tried using the latest versions of the jquery and jquery-ui framework but that iddn't haelp either.

If I downgrade to FullCalendar 1.5.3 the eventResized gets fired but I don't see the animation of the resizing in the week or day view.  Not that resizing works as it should in the month view perfectly.

Anyone seen this issue?

Comment: did you check the bug tracker?

Comment: Yes.  It is logged here: http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=eventResize&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=1543 but it is not very helpful